# If wordpress user is Name, show post category Y

Tags: php, wordpress

This is what I need so far:

In a custom page, I need to show different post titles, depending on the user who visits it. For example:

If user (id or name, whatever) is "username1", I want to display a list of posts of category 1. 
If user (id or name, whatever) is "username2", I want to display a list of posts of category 2.

What i have:

```
<?php
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
if ($user_id = 36) {?>
<?php $catquery = new WP_Query( 'resume_category=26&posts_per_page=50' 
); ?>
<ul>
<?php while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post(); ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php 
the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();}
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: If you have no clue where to start, what exactly do you expect from us?

Comment: @IsThisJavascript I mean, not exactly 'no clue', but all what i figured out is useless and right now I'm in big mess trying to figure it out.

Comment: I need some statement like 'if user is X, then show post category N'

Comment: Read the wordpress api... to get the user you would `wp_get_current_user();`... You can use `if()` statments to show and hide stuff but for a more dynamic answer you'll have to put in far more work yourself

Comment: @IsThisJavascript This is what I have right now:

Comment: Don't post code in the comments. Please remove it and add it to your OP and properly format it. Explain why the code you have isn't working or go into depth about your expected output vs your current output. I'm not that clued up on Wordpress so I'm not sure I can be of much help but atleast the question will be more prepared for someone who knows more about WP

Comment: @IsThisJavascript done.

Comment: What is the actual use for this, are you trying to create an "author page" or is it something else? Knowing the content rather than just the logic is just as helpful because there could be other ways to achieve the same result. You say post titles but do you mean different posts but just their title in the loop. Clarity is a useful thing.

Comment: @Kyon147 What i'm trying: I have custom posts categorized in custom categories. They're going to be used as Resumes where users identified as a"Candidate" WP role will fill. One of the fields to fill is asigned to the custom category, so they will be assigning the post to a category, for example "Category A". I want that "Category A" to be shown in a custom-page.php who acces the "employer". If the employer logged is user_id 36 (in the code above), the category to show is "resume_category=26". What i need to show is a list of the posts in that category, where the employer can access to read.

Comment: Does the employer control what categories they have access to or do you set that manually? Also, what is the current code doing vs what is expected? If you get errors can you please add them to your question.

Comment: @Kyon147 No, the employer only sees what i set. The code actually is doing nothing. Nothing is shown.

Comment: `if ($user_id = 36)` you are actually setting `$user_id` as 36, change that too `if ($user_id == 36)` (just one thing I noticed)

Comment: Did you mean to `echo the_permalink();` and `echo the_permalink();` because they are both missing that `echo` call

Comment: the_permalink echoes the code by default so you don't need the echo for that function and the same with the_title. I've added an answer and noticed the user_id = 36 so have tweaked the code.

The more dynamic answer is not the complete code but should be enough to get you on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is based off the info I know, so it might need tweaking but your "resume_category" looks like it a taxonomy which means you need to create your WP_Query a bit differently.

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();

if ($user_id == 36) {

    $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'YOUR POST TYPE',
            'posts_per_page' => 50,
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'resume_category',
                    'field'    => 'term_id',
                    'terms'    => '26',
                ),
            ),
        );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    echo '<ul>';

    while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

    echo"<li><a href=\"".the_permalink()."\"rel=\"bookmark\">".the_title()."</a></li>";

endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();

}
```

This is still a very manual process as you need to manually edit code for each user that joins for what they are allowed to see.

What you'd want to do is have a custom meta field that grabs the available options in resume_category as a select list, multi-selector etc that allows you to assign categories to users. You'd store the term_ids for the chosen ones of that taxonomy in the custom field.

Then you could do something like:

Get the users categories.

```
$user_categories = get_user_meta($user_id, 'categories_field');
```

Then build out your tax query.

```
$terms = array();
foreach $user_categories as $category {

$terms[] = $category; 

}
```

Then your query becomes:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'YOUR POST TYPE',
        'posts_per_page' => 50,
        'tax_query' => array(             
            $tax_query = array(
               'taxonomy' => 'resume_category',
               'field'    => 'term_id',
               'terms'    => $terms,
                )
            ),
        );
```

P.S: This code is untested as I am writing it straight in here but gives you the idea on how to make the category selection more dynamic.

Comment: Thanks, didn't work as expected, but been trying adding some shortcode snippets and echo them, and your answer gave me the final clue.

Comment: No problem glad it helped. WP can be a pain sometimes when building queries on custom taxonomies been there! You just want to make assigning categories dynamic as possible otherwise, if you have 100 employers you'd need 100 if statements! Good luck :)